# Use dataframe value as code or arguments in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframe, looking like this :

```
data_smmry <- data.frame(
  var_names=c("weather", "temperature", "date")
)

data_1 <- data.frame(
  date=c(1, 5, 15, 29),
  weather=c("sunny", "sunny", "cloudy", "windy"),
  temperature=c(25, 27, 20, 17)
)
```

I want to be able to add a "numeric" column to data_smmry, if the corresponding variable in data_1 is numeric or not, based on values in var_names.

This is what I tried so far :

`is.numeric(data_1$temperature)` return `TRUE`

`data_smmry[2,1]` return `"temperature"`

But what I want is :
`is.numeric(data_1$data_smmry[2,1])` to also return `TRUE`, but it currently returns `FALSE`

How can I use output of `data_smmry[2,1]` as code for `is.numeric(data_1$XXXX)` ?

Comment: This makes no sense. data_1 does not hold data_smmry, so `data_1$data_smmry` will return NULL.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[[` instead of `$`:

```
is.numeric(data_1[[data_smmry[2,1]]])
# [1] TRUE
```

`data_1$data_smmry[2,1]` tries to find a column called "data_smmry" in data_1, which isn’t what you want. Whereas `data_1[[data_smmry[2,1]]]` first evaluates `data_smmry[2,1]`, which returns `"temperature"`, and is then equivalent to `data_1[["temperature"]]`.

Answer (score 4):

Apply  `is.numeric` to the columns of `data_1`, then select the elements of this corresponding to `data_summry$var_names`.

```
> data_smmry$numeric <- sapply(data_1, is.numeric)[data_smmry$var_names]
> data_smmry
    var_names numeric
1     weather   FALSE
2 temperature    TRUE
3        date    TRUE
```

If instead you want a variable with the class, then replace `is.numeric` with `class`:

```
data_smmry$type <- sapply(data_1, class)[data_smmry$var_names]
```

Comment: I in fact just don’t want numeric or not, but also factor, and character. So I have a « type » column instead of the «  numeric » with value such as factor, character, numeric… using ifelse.

Comment: see my edit, you can just replace `is.numeric` with `class` to get this.

Comment: thanks! both your answer and @zephryl are working. His answer is the closest to what I expected given my initial code.